# PowerShell and iText - updating a PDF form - change font for single field value

Tags: powershell, pdf, fonts, itext, itext7

I am using PowerShell and itext to update a PDF form - pulling values from a database.  It works very well.  However - I have a new requirement - I need to update the font of the very last field to resemble a signature (a script font).  Searching for quite a while led me to this URL: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/itext/itext_setting_font.htm but I can't figure out how to convert that into PowerShell commands to change the font.  Any suggestions?

UPDATED:  Here is the code I'm using to create the PDF document.  Works well.  Want to change the font of the very last field (Signature) so it uses a script font - but cannot figure out how.

```
##-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Update Copy of Form
##-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if ($myCount -gt 0) {
    Write-Host Creating Document...
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Scripts\PDF\Common.Logging.Core.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Scripts\PDF\Common.Logging.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Scripts\PDF\itext.io.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Scripts\PDF\itext.kernel.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Scripts\PDF\itext.forms.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Scripts\PDF\itext.layout.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Scripts\PDF\BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll"

    $Reader = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader]::new("C:\Scripts\PDF\ETForm.pdf")
    $Reader.SetUnethicalReading($True)
    if (Test-Path "C:\Scripts\PDF\TuitionPolicy$myRequest.pdf") {
        Remove-Item "C:\Scripts\PDF\TuitionPolicy$myRequest.pdf"
    }
    $Writer = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter]::new("C:\Scripts\PDF\TuitionPolicy$myRequest.pdf")
    $PdfDoc = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]::new($Reader, $Writer)
    $Form = [iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm]::getAcroForm($PdfDoc, $True)
    $Fields = $Form.getFormFields()
    Write-Host $Fields.Keys
    ##$pdfDoc.Close()
    ##EXIT


    foreach($row in $DataSet.Tables[0]) {
        $myRequestor = $row.FRIENDLY_NAME
        $myLastDate = $row.LASTDAY.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
        $myLastD = Get-Date($myLastDate)
        $myTuition = '{0:C}' -f $row.TUITION
##        $myPREApp = $row.PREAPP
        $myD180 = $myLastD.AddDays(180)
        $myD180 = $myD180.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
        $myD270 = $myLastD.AddDays(270)
        $myD270 = $myD270.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
        $myD365 = $myLastD.AddDays(365)
        $myD365 = $myD365.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
    }

    ##----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Employee Name
    ##----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $Field = ($Fields | Where-Object {$_.key -eq "text_1jxwm"}).Value
    $Field.SetValue("$myRequestor")
    ##----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Last Date of Class
    ##----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $Field = ($Fields | Where-Object {$_.key -eq "text_2kwpq"}).Value
    $Field.SetValue("$myLastDate")
    ##----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Reimbursement Amount
    ##----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $Field = ($Fields | Where-Object {$_.key -eq "text_3xvwu"}).Value
    $Field.SetValue("$myTuition")
    ##----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Last Date + 180
    ##----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $Field = ($Fields | Where-Object {$_.key -eq "text_4wlyn"}).Value
    $Field.SetValue("$myD180")
    ##----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Last Date _ 270
    ##----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $Field = ($Fields | Where-Object {$_.key -eq "text_5aiwk"}).Value
    $Field.SetValue("$myD270")
    ##----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Last Date + 365
    ##----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $Field = ($Fields | Where-Object {$_.key -eq "text_6tmwp"}).Value
    $Field.SetValue("$myD365")
    ##----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Signature
    ##----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $Field = ($Fields | Where-Object {$_.key -eq "text_7byxl"}).Value
    $Field.SetValue("$myRequestor [from Request $myRequest]")


    $pdfDoc.Close()
}
```

Comment: Code included above

Comment: Hi, as I understand to reproduce/run your code we need an input PDF (that you are passing to the `PdfReader`) - can you share that?